# How can a Roomba turn as little as possible?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-geometry

Suppose I have a convex polygon $C$ and a radius $r>0$, and I seek a path $P$ that "covers" $C$, in the sense that any point $C$ is within distance $r$ of $P$: $$d(x,P)\leq r~\forall x\in C~,$$
where $d(x,P) := \min_{x'\in P} \|x-x'\|$.   My question:  are there any analytical results (lower/upper bounds, etc.) that describe the *minimum amount of turning* needed to cover $P$?  The figure below shows three covering paths of a rectangle, and the upper path has a total of $9\pi$ radians worth of rotation whereas the lower two have $3\pi$.

[image: Three covering paths]

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [Planning Algorithms](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu) book, especially section 7.6 on coverage planning.

Comment: The greedy algorithm is:  go as far as you can in uncovered area without turning, then turn to follow the boundary of the uncovered area.  This leads to the last path.  Does every polygon have some greedy path which is optimal?

Answer (score 4):

The following paper studies this "milling" problem (generalized) from a complexity viewpoint:

> Arkin, E. M., Bender, M. A., Demaine, E. D., Fekete, S. P., Mitchell, J. S., & Sethia, S. (2005). Optimal covering tours with turn costs. *SIAM Journal on Computing*, 35(3), 531-566. ([Preliminary arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0309014).)

Among many results, they prove

> that the covering tour problem with turn costs is NP-complete,
>   even if the objective is purely to minimize the number of turns, the pocket is
>   orthogonal (rectilinear), and the cutter must move axis-parallel.

The provide several approximations algorithms for variants of the
problem. For the Roomba variant in which the orthogonal polygon
may have holes and the tour is axis-parallel, they achieve
a $3.75$-approximation ratio.

---

[image: Milling]

        
<sup>Fig.5.2.b: An optimal tour: square with square hole.</sup>

---

There is literature on NC milling of *convex* shapes, but I cannot access
any the papers, so I am not certain of their relevance:

> - Wang, Hsu-Pin, Heng Chang, and Richard A. Wysk. "An analytical approach to optimize NC tool path planning for face milling flat convex polygonal surfaces." *IIE transactions* 20.3 (1988): 325-332.
> - Prabhu, Prasad V., Anand K. Gramopadhye, and Hsu-pin Wang. "A general mathematical model for optimizing NC tool path for face milling of flat convex polygonal surfaces." *The International Journal of Production Research* 28.1 (1990): 101-130.
> - Deshmukh, Abhijit V., M. M. Barash, and Hsin-Pang Wang. On selection of tool path orientations for generating prismatic features. School of Industrial Engineering, Purdue University, 1993.

Comment: I would expect the complexity to come from the holes, but the question asked about convex polygons.

Comment: @MattF.: Yes, or perhaps from non-convexity (even without holes).